# Random processes

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, random

I hope someone could tell me how to explain that "random process is continuous by probability" and "random process is differentiated by probability"? I know that definitions are these:

1. Given a time $t ∈ T$, $X$ is said to be continuous in probability at $t_0$ if, for all $ε > 0$, 
   $\lim_{h \to 0}  P(∣X_{t_0+h}−X_{t_0}∣ >ε)=0$. 
   If the process is continuous in probability at every point, then it is continuous in probability.
2. Process $X_t$ is differentiated by probability at $t_0$ if $\exists$ limit

   $\lim_{h \to 0} (X_{t_0 + h} - X_{t_0})/h $ by probability.

Thanks a lot!

I need to explain what "random process is continuous by probability" and "random process is differentiated by probability" mean.

Comment: What do you mean by explain? By the way, being continuous in probability and being continuous with probability one (which is your definition 1) are not the same.

Comment: So the definition of continuity by probability would be:
Given a time t ∈ T, X is said to be continuous in probability at t if, for all ε > 0,

 $   \lim_{s \to t} \mathbf{P} \left( \left\{ \omega \in \Omega \left| \big| X_{s} (\omega) - X_{t} (\omega) \big| \geq \varepsilon \right. \right\} \right) = 0. $
If the process is continuous in probability at every t, then it is continuous in probability.

I need to explain what "random process is continuous by probability" and "random process is differentiated by probability" mean.

Answer (score 0):

1 means that for every $t_0$, the probability of a discontinuity happening at $t_0$ is zero. That doesn't mean, by the way, that there are no discontinuities anywhere; it only says that there are no "scheduled" discontinuities.